# Rock-scissors-paper-game with ruby def compare does not work

Tags: ruby

I tried to create the game. Here is my code:

```
puts "Welcome to our Rock, Paper, Scissors Game"

puts "Do you want to play? (yes/no)"
answer = gets.chomp.downcase
while answer == "yes" do

options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
computer_choice = options[rand(options.length)]

puts "Please choose Rock, Paper or Scissors!"
player_choice = gets.chomp.downcase

def compare
  if (player_choice == "rock" && computer_choice == "scissors")
    puts "computer choice is: " + computer_choice + " , you win! :)"
  elsif (player_choice == "rock" && computer_choice == "paper")
    puts "computer choice is: " + computer_choice + " ,computer wins :("
  elsif (player_choice == "paper" && computer_choice == "scissors")
    puts "computer choice is: " + computer_choice + " ,computer wins :("
  elsif (player_choice == "paper" && computer_choice == "rock")
    puts "computer choice is: " + computer_choice + " , you win! :)"
  elsif (player_choice == "scissors" && computer_choice == "rock")
    puts "computer choice is: " + computer_choice + " ,computer wins :("
  elsif (player_choice == "scissors" && computer_choice == "paper")
    puts "computer choice is: " + computer_choice + " , you win! :)"
  elsif (player_choice === computer_choice)
    puts "It's a tie!"
  else
    puts "Error"
  end
end
end
```

It repeats asking me my choice, and does not proceed to my def compare. What am I missing?

Comment: Consider using a hash: `h = { "rock"=>"scissors", "paper"=>"rock", "scissors"=>"paper" }`.  Then player wins if `h[player_choice) == computer_choice`, computer wins if `h[computer_choice] == player_choice`, else it's a tie.

Comment: Try a structure like this. `loop do; puts "keep playin'?"; break if "gets.chomp.downcase == "n"; loop do; puts "what's your choice?"; player_choice = gets.chomp; if h.has_key?(player_choice); <see if win, lose or tie>; break; else; puts "'#{player_choice}' is invalid, try again"; end; end`.

Comment: Thanks, your ideas taught me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Let's break this into three parts. First, let's write the main loop for playing the game:

```
puts "Welcome to our Rock, Paper, Scissors Game"

loop do
  puts "Do you want to play? (yes/no)"
  answer = gets.chomp.downcase
  if answer == "yes"
    play_game
  elsif answer == "no"
    puts "Bye!"
    break
  elsif
    puts "Invalid answer (must be 'yes' or 'no')"
  end
end
```

This fixes your first issue, where the "do you want to play" is not actually being looped.

Now, let's define the `play_game` method:

```
def play_game
  options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
  computer_choice = options.sample

  loop do
    puts "Please choose Rock, Paper or Scissors!"
    player_choice = gets.chomp.downcase
    if options.include?(player_choice)
      compare(player_choice, computer_choice)
      break
    else
      puts "Invalid answer (must be 'rock', 'paper' or 'scissors')"
    end
  end
end
```

This fixes your second issue, there the player got stuck in an infinite loop within each game.

Now finally, let's define the `compare` method:

```
def compare(player_choice, computer_choice)
  puts "Computer choice is: " + computer_choice + ". "

  if(player_choice == "rock" && computer_choice == "scissors")
    puts "You win! :)"
  elsif(player_choice == "rock" && computer_choice == "paper")
    puts "Computer wins :("
  elsif(player_choice == "paper" && computer_choice == "scissors")
    puts "Computer wins :("
  elsif(player_choice == "paper" && computer_choice == "rock")
    puts "You win! :)"
  elsif(player_choice == "scissors" && computer_choice == "rock")
    puts "Computer wins :("
  elsif(player_choice == "scissors" && computer_choice == "paper")
    puts "You win! :)"
  else
    puts "It's a tie!"
  end
end
```

You could probably improve that method further, but I have at least removed the biggest duplication between `puts` statements.

Put this all together, and here is a fully working version of the game:

```
def play_game 
  options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"] 
  computer_choice = options.sample 

  loop do 
    puts "Please choose Rock, Paper or Scissors!" 
    player_choice = gets.chomp.downcase 
    if options.include?(player_choice) 
      compare(player_choice, computer_choice) 
      break 
    else 
      puts "Invalid answer (must be 'rock', 'paper' or 'scissors')" 
    end 
  end 
end 

def compare(player_choice, computer_choice) 
  puts "Computer choice is: " + computer_choice + ". " 

  if(player_choice == "rock" && computer_choice == "scissors") 
    puts "You win! :)" 
  elsif(player_choice == "rock" && computer_choice == "paper") 
    puts "Computer wins :(" 
  elsif(player_choice == "paper" && computer_choice == "scissors") 
    puts "Computer wins :(" 
  elsif(player_choice == "paper" && computer_choice == "rock") 
    puts "You win! :)" 
  elsif(player_choice == "scissors" && computer_choice == "rock") 
    puts "Computer wins :(" 
  elsif(player_choice == "scissors" && computer_choice == "paper") 
    puts "You win! :)" 
  else 
    puts "It's a tie!" 
  end 
end 


puts "Welcome to our Rock, Paper, Scissors Game" 

loop do 
  puts "Do you want to play? (yes/no)" 
  answer = gets.chomp.downcase 
  if answer == "yes" 
    play_game 
  elsif answer == "no" 
    puts "Bye!" 
    break 
  elsif 
    puts "Invalid answer (must be 'yes' or 'no')" 
  end 
end
```

There are many ways that this could be improved further, but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions! I tried your several ideas and learned a lot, thank you!